# ant script to remove svn:ignored directories & files

Tags: svn, ant

We use svn:ingored to mask out externally sourced files (aka compiled or copied) from our projects.
Is there a way to remove just those files and directories as part of an ant cleanup target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used svnant, but from the [documentation](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/introduction.html) it seems they provide some selectors, a [svnIgnored selector](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/selectors.html#svnignored) f.e.,
 so in theory it should work like that :

```
 <delete>
  <fileset dir="workingcopy">
   <svnIgnored/>
  </fileset>
 </delete>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a clean target that gets rid of those, It will work in all cases and even if you get the source by doing an svn export.  And it's very clear from looking at the build script what's being deleted.  It will also still work if your team moves to [insert new SCM system here].

```
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${reports.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="init" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}" />
</target>
```

Comment: I do have a clean target but not all temp files are within disposable directories. Builds tend to form a composite of both derived files and version controlled files. svn:ignore is the easiest way to enumerate that list as it changes rather than cluttering up the make file.

Comment: hmm... seems way easier to have all the derived artifacts under a small number of disposable directories (like build and dist), especially if the list changes with regularity.  Did you find a workable solution for your team?